# Alternative to pdf to use with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, docx

the problem come from converting other files like docx xlsx to pdf it so defuclt by manged code or costly by 3rd party solution, so what is the altenative to pdf that i can easly convert docx to and then i can view it in web browser by asp.net c# code

Comment: You say you want to view it in a web browser, so why not (X)HTML?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your own server you can use Word automation to accomplish that. Check out this example from Microsoft: [Saving Word 2007 Documents to PDF and XPS Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305.aspx). This solution requires Word 2007 and [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en) installed on server machine.

Also, check out this solution: [Scripting PDF Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627497/scripting-pdf-creation)

They are saying that you can install virtual printer that will print postscript to a file, and then using a GhostScript to convert postscript to PDF. All this can be automated, but also requires bunch of software installed and configured on server machine.

For any other solution like "Direct DOCX to PDF converter" without Word 2007 installation you will have to purchase some other 3rd component/library. If you will choose that solution, my suggestion is: [Aspose.Words for .NET.](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)

If you really want to avoid all this i mentioned earlier then take your time, download [Open XML SKD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx), download [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library and start writing a code that will transform Open XML format that Word 2007 is based on to PDF. I would suggest this only if you dont have anything else to do and you have "a lot" of free time.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757  Microsoft dosn't support or recommend that and i tested it by my self i'm asking about alternative to avoid pdf

Comment: Aspose.Words is the way I usually choose, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPS format, that you can get from office 2007 or 2010. But only Vista and 7 has built-in support. For Windows XP your customer must install .NET Framework 3 because XPS Viewer is a part of it and using framework libraries. There are others XPS Viewers, you can find even based on Silverlight because xps format is similar with xaml, but they are all commercial.

Comment: the same problem for converting docx to pdf